# Add every file inside a folder

Tags: excel, vba, image, addition

I'm trying to do a macro that let's the user select a folder with more folders inside, this folders could have images .jpg or .png. What I want is that the macro adds only the image files in the excel, any image file. What it does right now is that adds the images but only if they have for name 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and so on.

```
Dim Secfolder As String
MsgBox ("Busque y seleccione la carpeta que contiene las carpetas de los sectores en el punto que realizará.")
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

.Title = "Buscar carpeta"
.ButtonName = "Aceptar"
.InitialFileName = "C:\"

If .Show = -1 Then
 Secfolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End If

Sheets("Matriz_de_Hallazgos").Select

l = 1

For i = 1 To 200
idm = (Worksheets("Matriz_de_Hallazgos").Cells(i + 2, 1))

If idm = 1 Then
Application.SpellingOptions.IgnoreCaps = True
 ' Colocar la ruta de las fotos; las fotos deben llamarse como números. Ej: 1.jpg'
    RutaCompleta = Secfolder & "\" & "sector " & idm & "\" & l & ".jpg"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 2, 3).Select
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=RutaCompleta, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=0, Height:=0)
        .LockAspectRatio = 0
        .Top = ActiveCell.Top
        .Left = ActiveCell.Left
        .Width = ActiveCell.Width
        .Height = ActiveCell.Height
    End With
    l = l + 1
End If
Next i
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is adding `1.jpg,2.jpg` etc. because you have used `l` variable in the following line.

```
RutaCompleta = Secfolder & "\" & "sector " & idm & "\" & l & ".jpg"
```

You will have to use actual file name instead of `l` variable.

You can use the following to loop through the files for the selected folder.

```
FolderName = "D:\" 'Replace it with selected folder
Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FSOFolder = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(FolderName)
Set FSOFile = FSOFolder.Files
'Use For Each loop to loop through each file in the folder
For Each FSOFile In FSOFile
    'Insert actions to be perfomed on each file
    MsgBox FSOFile.Name
Next
```